# How to retrieve developerPayload using the Order ID in android

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Is there a Google Play Developer API that can let me retrieve the details of any purchase using the Order ID only.

The only API I can find that is related to what I need is this https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products and it is using the purchaseToken to retrive a purchase resource.

Right now my app does this

1. User signs up to my app, the user is then assigned a unique userid.
2. When a user upgrades the app verifies the payment on my remote server setting the developerPayload to the user's userid.
3. Remote server verifies the payment ([using this](https://github.com/mgoldsborough/google-play-in-app-billing-verification)) if payment is valid. It will then update that account linked to the userid and then it will save the details of payment to database and return an OK signal to the android device.
4. When android device receives an OK signal it will then consume the item.

So when Step 3 encounters an unexpected error and failed to save the payment details to the database and the app consumes the item I wont be able to know the value of developerPayload of that Order ID. Checking the [merchant page](https://payments.google.com/merchant/) doesnt help because it doesnt display the developerPayload.

Is there any other way to check the developerPayload? Should I change the implementation of my in-app billing payment?